# Move child elements above grandparent and copy elements below into it in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml-file that I need to do a ton of transformations on, but one of them I know for fact I have no clue on how to approach. I've spend the last half hour searching and I am still completely blank on this on:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<catalogList>
<product>
    <status>new</status>
    <product-id>1</product-id>
    <catId>1001</catId>
    <title>Garmin Nuvi 2589LMT</title>
    <model>2589LMT</model>
    <line>Nuvi</line>
    <brand>Garmin</brand>
    <eanList>
        <ean>0753759115166</ean>
        <ean>0753759115173</ean>
        <ean>0753759115395</ean>
    </eanList>
    <imageUrlList>
        <imageUrl size="small">http://imagesmall</imageUrl>
        <imageUrl size="medium">http://imagemedium</imageUrl>
        <imageUrl size="large">http://imagelarge</imageUrl>
    </imageUrlList>
    <specificationList>
        <specification name="Heade_Manuf" translation="Mærke">
            <specificationValue>Garmin</specificationValue>
        </specification>
        <specification name="GPS_Syste_Desti" translation="Anvendelsesområde">
            <specificationValue>Bil</specificationValue>
        </specification>
        <specification name="GPS_Syste_Funct_Servi" translation="Funktioner">
            <specificationValue>Rejse Planlægning</specificationValue>
        </specification>
        <specification name="Displ_Type" translation="Skærmtype">
            <specificationValue>Monokrom skærm</specificationValue>
        </specification>
        <specification name="DISP_Displ_Size" translation="Skærmstørrelse">
            <specificationValue>5 tommer</specificationValue>
        </specification>
        <specification name="Built_Displ_Resol" translation="Skærmopløsning">
            <specificationValue>480 x 272</specificationValue>
        </specification>
        <specification name="DISP_Width" translation="Bredde">
            <specificationValue>13,8 cm</specificationValue>
        </specification>
        <specification name="DISP_Depth" translation="Dybde">
            <specificationValue>1,8 cm</specificationValue>
        </specification>
        <specification name="DISP_Heigh" translation="Højde">
            <specificationValue>8,4 cm</specificationValue>
        </specification>
        <specification name="DISP_Weigh" translation="Vægt">
            <specificationValue>184 g</specificationValue>
        <!-- </specification> -->
        <specification name="DISP_Batte_Life" translation="Batterilevetid">
            <specificationValue>2Timer</specificationValue>
        </specification>
        <specification name="Type" translation="Type">
            <specificationValue>GPS</specificationValue>
        </specification>
        <specification name="Batte" translation="Batteri">
            <specificationValue>Litium-ion</specificationValue>
        </specification>
    </specificationList>
</product>
<product>
    <status>new</status>
    <product-id>3</product-id>
    <catId>1002</catId>
    <title>Garmin Forerunner 920XT</title>
    <model>920XT</model>
    <line>Forerunner</line>
    <brand>Garmin</brand>
    <eanList>
        <ean>0753759108731</ean>
        <ean>0753759108748</ean>
        <ean>0753759125707</ean>
        <ean>0753759125714</ean>
    </eanList>
    <imageUrlList>
        <imageUrl size="small">http://imagesmall</imageUrl>
        <imageUrl size="medium">http://imagemedium</imageUrl>
        <imageUrl size="large">http://imagelarge</imageUrl>
    </imageUrlList>
    <specificationList>
        <specification name="Heade_Manuf" translation="Mærke">
            <specificationValue>Garmin</specificationValue>
        </specification>
        <specification name="GPS_Syste_Desti" translation="Anvendelsesområde">
            <specificationValue>GPS Watch</specificationValue>
        </specification>
        <specification name="Misce_Water" translation="Vandtæt">
            <specificationValue>Vandtæt</specificationValue>
        </specification>
        <specification name="Type" translation="Type">
            <specificationValue>GPS</specificationValue>
        </specification>
    </specificationList>
</product>
<catalogList>
```

The end result should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<catalogList>
<product>
    <ean>0753759115166</ean>
    <status>new</status>
    <product-id>1</product-id>
    <catId>1001</catId>
    <title>Garmin Nuvi 2589LMT</title>
    <model>2589LMT</model>
    <line>Nuvi</line>
    <brand>Garmin</brand>
    <imageUrlList>
        <imageUrlsmall>http://imagesmall</imageUrlsmall>
        <imageUrlmedium>http://imagemedium</imageUrlmedium>
        <imageUrllarge>http://imagelarge</imageUrllarge>
    </imageUrlList>
    <specificationList>
        Mærke:Garmin;Anvendelsesområde:Bil;Funktioner:Rejse Planlægning;Skærmtype:Monokrom skærm;Skærmstørrelse:5 tommer;Skærmopløsning::480 x 272;Bredde:13,8 cm;Dybde:1,8 cm;Højde:8,4 cm;Vægt=184 g;Batterilevetid=2Timer;Type:GPS;Batteri:Litium-ion
    </specificationList>
</product>
<product>
    <ean>0753759115173</ean>
    <status>new</status>
    <product-id>1</product-id>
    <catId>1001</catId>
    <title>Garmin Nuvi 2589LMT</title>
    <model>2589LMT</model>
    <line>Nuvi</line>
    <brand>Garmin</brand>
    <imageUrlList>
        <imageUrlsmall>http://imagesmall</imageUrlsmall>
        <imageUrlmedium>http://imagemedium</imageUrlmedium>
        <imageUrllarge>http://imagelarge</imageUrllarge>
    </imageUrlList>
    <specificationList>
        Mærke:Garmin;Anvendelsesområde:Bil;Funktioner:Rejse Planlægning;Skærmtype:Monokrom skærm;Skærmstørrelse:5 tommer;Skærmopløsning::480 x 272;Bredde:13,8 cm;Dybde:1,8 cm;Højde:8,4 cm;Vægt=184 g;Batterilevetid=2Timer;Type:GPS;Batteri:Litium-ion
    </specificationList>
</product>
<product>
    <ean>0753759115395</ean>
    <status>new</status>
    <product-id>1</product-id>
    <catId>1001</catId>
    <title>Garmin Nuvi 2589LMT</title>
    <model>2589LMT</model>
    <line>Nuvi</line>
    <brand>Garmin</brand>
    <imageUrlList>
        <imageUrlsmall>http://imagesmall</imageUrlsmall>
        <imageUrlmedium>http://imagemedium</imageUrlmedium>
        <imageUrllarge>http://imagelarge</imageUrllarge>
    </imageUrlList>
    <specificationList>
        Mærke:Garmin;Anvendelsesområde:Bil;Funktioner:Rejse Planlægning;Skærmtype:Monokrom skærm;Skærmstørrelse:5 tommer;Skærmopløsning::480 x 272;Bredde:13,8 cm;Dybde:1,8 cm;Højde:8,4 cm;Vægt=184 g;Batterilevetid=2Timer;Type:GPS;Batteri:Litium-ion
    </specificationList>
</product>
<product>
    <ean>0753759108731</ean>
    <status>new</status>
    <product-id>3</product-id>
    <catId>1002</catId>
    <title>Garmin Forerunner 920XT</title>
    <model>920XT</model>
    <line>Forerunner</line>
    <brand>Garmin</brand>
    <imageUrlList>
        <imageUrlsmall>http://imagesmall3</imageUrlsmall>
        <imageUrlmedium>http://imagemedium3</imageUrlmedium>
        <imageUrllarge>http://imagelarge3</imageUrllarge>
    </imageUrlList>
    <specificationList>
        <speMærke:Garmin;Anvendelsesområde:GPS Watch;Vandtæt:Vandtæt;Type:GPS
        </specification>
    </specificationList>
</product>
<product>
    <ean>0753759108748</ean>
    <status>new</status>
    <product-id>3</product-id>
    <catId>1002</catId>
    <title>Garmin Forerunner 920XT</title>
    <model>920XT</model>
    <line>Forerunner</line>
    <brand>Garmin</brand>
    <imageUrlList>
        <imageUrlsmall>http://imagesmall3</imageUrlsmall>
        <imageUrlmedium>http://imagemedium3</imageUrlmedium>
        <imageUrllarge>http://imagelarge3</imageUrllarge>
    </imageUrlList>
    <specificationList>
        Mærke:Garmin;Anvendelsesområde:GPS Watch;Vandtæt:Vandtæt;Type:GPS
    </specificationList>
</product>
<product>
    <ean>0753759125707</ean>
    <status>new</status>
    <product-id>3</product-id>
    <catId>1002</catId>
    <title>Garmin Forerunner 920XT</title>
    <model>920XT</model>
    <line>Forerunner</line>
    <brand>Garmin</brand>
    <imageUrlList>
        <imageUrlsmall>http://imagesmall3</imageUrlsmall>
        <imageUrlmedium>http://imagemedium3</imageUrlmedium>
        <imageUrllarge>http://imagelarge3</imageUrllarge>
    </imageUrlList>
    <specificationList>
        Mærke:Garmin;Anvendelsesområde:GPS Watch;Vandtæt:Vandtæt;Type:GPS
    </specificationList>
</product>
<product>
    <ean>0753759125714</ean>
    <status>new</status>
    <product-id>3</product-id>
    <catId>1002</catId>
    <title>Garmin Forerunner 920XT</title>
    <model>920XT</model>
    <line>Forerunner</line>
    <brand>Garmin</brand>
    <imageUrlList>
        <imageUrlsmall>http://imagesmall3</imageUrlsmall>
        <imageUrlmedium>http://imagemedium3</imageUrlmedium>
        <imageUrllarge>http://imagelarge3</imageUrllarge>
    </imageUrlList>
    <specificationList>
        Mærke:Garmin;Anvendelsesområde:GPS Watch;Vandtæt:Vandtæt;Type:GPS
    </specificationList>
</product>
<catalogList>
```

Meaning I need to make the following changes:
Take the eanList and for every ean number make that a new product containing every element from the existing product with the ean number added as an element. This part I am completely lost on.

My Xslt so far looks like

```
<xsl:param name="counter" select="1"/>


<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="/catalogList/product/imageUrlList/imageUrl">

    <xsl:variable name="vSize" select="@size"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="{$vSize}">
    <xsl:value-of select="current()"></xsl:value-of>
  </xsl:element>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/catalogList/product/specificationList">
  <specifications>
    <xsl:for-each select="specification"><xsl:value-of select="@translation"></xsl:value-of>:<xsl:value-of select="specificationValue"></xsl:value-of>;</xsl:for-each>  
  </specifications>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/catalogList/product">
  <product>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </product>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="/catalogList">
  <catalog>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</catalog>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="*[self::ean]">
    <eanproduct>
      <xsl:apply-templates />

  </eanproduct>

</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like this (uses XSLT 2.0 constructs, but could easily be expressed in XSLT 1.0, just a bit more verbosely):

```
<xsl:template match="product">
  <xsl:variable name="p" select="."/>
  <xsl:for-each select="eanList/ean">
    <product>
      <ean><xsl:value-of select="."/></ean>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$p/(status, product-id, catId, 
                    title, model, line, brand, imageUrlList)"/>
      <specificationList>
        <xsl:value-of select="specificationList/specification/
              concat(@translation, ':', specificationValue)" separator=";"/>
      </specificationList>
    </product>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: wow, I was finally getting somewhere myself and then you write a code piece that is less than half of mine :) Looking forward to test it.